# Как в телеграмм бот может передать gif в группу?

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot

Есть бот - админ группы.
Как заставить его публиковать gif файлы в группе?
Gif передает юзер.
Вот как я пытаюсь.

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['document'])
def handle_document(message):
    print(message.document.file_id)
    bot.send_animation(CHANNEL_ID, message.document.file_id)
```

В таком виде gif не передается. И вывода не экран нет.